# Android IntentService's onDestroy not called in foreground IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have an `IntentService`.

In its `OnCreate` I call `startForeground(1, buildUpdatingAssignmentsNotification());`

```
@NonNull
private Notification buildUpdatingAssignmentsNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.EMPTY)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0})
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(ASSIGNMENTS_GETTER_STARTED_MESSAGE)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setProgress(0, 0, true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
}
```

In the end of `OnHandleIntent` I call `stopForeground(true);`(It is being called since I see the notification disappear) but the `OnDestroy` method is not being called.

It works properly if I dont use the foreground thing and also this problem only happens when I start the `IntentService` from an activity and close the app before the `IntentService` finishes (it finishes the `OnHandleIntent` anyway but doesnt call the `OnDestroy`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You figure it out any solution?